# ViewPager only displaying last fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm setting up a Tabbed ViewPager layout based on the wizard in Android Studio.
I've created two fragments to use in the ViewPager, as well as the included placeholder.

Only the last fragment is shown, whichever tab its on.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, TunerFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, SettingsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        Log.v("tab selected", tab.getPosition() + ":" + tab.toString() +" - "+fragmentTransaction.toString());
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
        Log.v("onFragmentInteraction",uri.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String id) {
        Log.v("onFragmentInteraction",id);

    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

            Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
            Log.v("MainActivity","position:"+ position);

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new TunerFragment();
                case 1:
                    fragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
                case 2:
                    fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_tuner).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_scale).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_settings).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the breaks inside the switch block which caused the fragment to always be SettingsFragment:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        Log.v("MainActivity","position:"+ position);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new TunerFragment();
        // should insert break;
            case 1:
                fragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        // should insert break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new SettingsFragment();
            default:
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }
```

Comment: Ah yes of course, I had it returning from the switch before and didn't add in the break statements!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);`. This is setting the current item to `1`. This should be done in the adapter.